# jQuery click event trigger $.confirm stacking the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-confirm

I want a button to submit a form when is clicked or the enter key is pressed on focus, but before I want to display a confirm alert displaying some information to the user using [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/), when he accepts the modal then the target form must submit.

For some reason when I confirm the first time is OK, but when I do a second time looks like the $.confirm is stacking, then is displayed two times, after confirm if I click again it's displaying 3 times... Why this is happening?

I'm using data attributes to select the element plus form target, there is a fiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/z3mn21dz/7/

*Note: I don't want a walk around, I know there's a lot of possible alternatives but I want to know what's wrong.*

**HTML**

```
<button data-role="confirm" data-target="target">
  Submit
</button>

<h1>Form to submit</h1>
<form action="" id="target"><input type="text"></form>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function($){

$('[data-role="confirm"]').on('keyup click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');

    if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.type == "click")
    {
    $(this).confirm({
      title: 'Confirm!',
      content: 'Simple confirm!',
      buttons: {
          confirm: function () {
              $.alert('Confirmed!');
          },
          cancel: function () {
              $.alert('Canceled!');
          },
          somethingElse: {
              text: 'Something else',
              btnClass: 'btn-blue',
              keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
              action: function(){
                  $.alert('Something else?');
              }
          }
      }
    });
    }

})
});
```

Comment: From your code it appears that the "confirm" function is not working, not even after two clicks. If it was working at all I would be seeing german words and an exclamation triangle with danger buttons, which I dont. The problem is not in the two-timed function

Comment: @mnemosdev Sorry my example was wrong, now I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle updated your entire JS code like below and it seems working properly. P.S. Line number line 9 on the script `$(this).confirm({` was changed to  `$.confirm({`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[data-role="confirm"]').on('keyup click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data('target');

        if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.type == "click")
        {
        $.confirm({

          icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
          confirmButton: 'bestätigen',
          confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
          cancelButton: 'abbrechen',
          confirm: function(ee){
             $( "#"+target ).submit();
          }
        });
        }

    })
});
```

**UPDATE**
The Javascript part is updated as

```
$(document).ready(function($){


    $('[data-role="confirm"]').on('keyup click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data('target');

        if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.type == "click")
        {
        $.confirm({
          title: 'Confirm!',
          content: 'Simple confirm!',
          buttons: {
              confirm: function () {
                  $.alert('Confirmed! Target: '+target);
              },
              cancel: function () {
                  $.alert('Canceled!');
              },
              somethingElse: {
                  text: 'Something else',
                  btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                  keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
                  action: function(){
                      $.alert('Something else?');
                  }
              }
          }
        });
        }

    })
});
```

The reason for your stack was that you were using `$(this).confirm` instead of `$.confirm`. i.e., the confirm function was associated with JQuery, and since you used `this` it was not getting bound at first instance. Secondly, the syntax of confirm needs buttons to take the necessary actions which too was missing before. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: But the `confirm:` action is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/z3mn21dz/8/

Comment: When the buttons are added the confirm action will work
`buttons: {
         confirm: function () {
            $.alert('Confirmed!');
         },
          cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Cancelled!');
         },`

Comment: update your answer and add a explanation why It was stacking please :)

Comment: Updated as per the request

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('[data-role="confirm"]').on('keyup click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data('target');

        if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.type == "click")
        {
        $(this).confirm({
          title: 'Confirm!',
          content: 'Simple confirm!',
          buttons: {
              confirm: function (e) {
                  $.alert('Confirmed! Target: '+target);
                  $('.jconfirm').remove();
              },
              cancel: function () {
                  $.alert('Canceled!');
              },
              somethingElse: {
                  text: 'Something else',
                  btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                  keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
                  action: function(){
                      $.alert('Something else?');
                  }
              }
          }
        });
        }

    })
});
```

The reason is, once you click 'confirm' button, a new element 'jconfirm' is created,you can see the 'Elements' tab, so you need to remove it everytime.

Comment: Please post your code in your answer and not as an image link. There's no guarantee that image will exist in the future, and it's not very clear what changes you are proposing OP makes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because your button is outside the form element, it might cause the issue
Take the button within your form element and include `type="sumbit"` in the button.
Look the following function, customize as you needed.

```
function confirmDel(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
        resizable:false,
        height:"auto",
        width:300,
        modal:true,
        buttons:{
            "Confirm Delete":function(){
                  e.target.submit();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },Cancel:function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    }
   }
```

Call this function in the `onsubmit` event of your form. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please focus on my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? :)

Comment: why you need e.preventDefault(); in the code as you are not submitting the form that's not necessary. May it cause the issue i am not sure, give it a shot

Comment: Because on my original code I got the `button` inside a form but it submits another one.

Comment: better you have separate button for separate form and don't use one button for two different form submit, because of this also you might get the error....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-define the confirm object in every click, only once. In order to prevent the sticky confirm dialog behaviour you can add a control variable, so the confirm definition only happens once. Following your code:

```
$('[data-role="confirm"]').on('keyup click', function (e) {
  if ($(this).data.defined) {return;}
  $(this).data.defined = true;
  //...
```

There are other issues you might want to fix, as the keyup event should be attached to the input field rather than the button (I'm guessing). This workaround is focused on the confirm behaviour only.